# Excel - join values in one cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with parcel numbers and ID numbers of buildings on them. If building_id is NULL, then there is no building on that parcel.

[image]

What I need to do is to join building numbers in same cell delimited by hashtag # if they are on the same parcel. Example below:

[image]

There are two buildings (1998 and 58) on parcel 1001/10, so building id field should look like "1998#58". How can I do this in excel?

Comment: Will a `parcel_id` only ever have a maximum of 2 `building_id`s? Or can it have multiple?

Comment: You can do this pretty simply with Power Query (available since 2010).  Just group by `parcel_id`, then convert the resultant table to a list and split it using `#` as the delimiter.

Comment: @Martin it can have multiple buildings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on access to the [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function.

> ***Note:*** This feature is available on Windows or Mac if you have Office 2019, or if you have an Office 365 subscription. If you are an
>   Office 365 subscriber, make sure you have the latest version of
>   Office.

[image]

- Paste column A in D, remove duplicates with build-in function (there are formulas if you need to use them for this also)
- Formula in `E2`:

  ```
  =TEXTJOIN("#",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$10=D2,$B$2:$B$10,""))
  ```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

- Drag down...